# select column_name from table where column_name = all_values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a REST endpoint like this:

`www.icecreamstore.com/stock?brand=hershey&flavour=vanilla`

Now,

Both `brand` and `flavour` are optional.

So the following are also perfectly valid :

`www.icecreamstore.com/stock?flavour=vanilla`

`www.icecreamstore.com/stock?brand=hershey`

`www.icecreamstore.com/stock`

These APIs map to a SQL query :

`select count(*) from stock where brand=? and flavour=?`

Is it possible to utilize a single query, instead of writing a separate query for each combination of request parameters.

Alternatively,

Is it possible to write a query like this :

`select count(*) from stock where brand=* and flavour=*`

**Note :** I am currently managing with `LIKE` using `column_name LIKE '%%'` in the case of the absence of request parameters. But what if the columns do not store values of type string.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular situation, the simplest way might be:

```
select count(*)
from stock
where brand = coalesce(?, brand) and flavour = coalesce(?, flavour);
```

This assumes that `brand` and `flavour` are never `NULL`.

If they can be `NULL`, you can use `is not distinct from`:

```
select count(*)
from stock
where brand is not distinct from coalesce(?, brand) and
      flavour is not distinct from coalesce(?, flavour);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all values you can also write an static value in the query to bypass if the first condition is not true:

```
select count(*)
from stock
where (brand=<to get single> or 'allBrand'='allBrand') AND
 (flavour=<to get single> or 'allFlavour'='allFlavour')
```